# Python 3 tkinter message box highlight the "No" button?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, messagebox

I want to create a message box that confirms the intent to delete.

```
    def delete_action(self):
    s_id = self.selected_ID_entry.get()
    s_name = self.seletedEntry.get()
    answer = messagebox.askquestion("Delete?","Are you sure you want to delete {}".format(s_name), icon='warning')

    if answer == 'yes':
        #deleted function here
    else:
        #not deleted function here
```

**How to highlight the "No" button instead of the "Yes" button?**

[image: something like this]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set a default value as a keyword argument; something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

def quid():
    messagebox.askyesno("What", "What???????????", default='no')

root = tk.Tk()
ask = tk.Button(root, text='what?', command=quid)
ask.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks, Mr. I want to ask do you know how to change the color of highlight from blue to "red"? is it possible?

Comment: You are welcome. I am afraid I don't know; I think tkinter is using your system settings for the dialogs, but does not give you access to the level of control you have in mind.